# Can't suss out the (likely) last error in a rounding function (Python)

Tags: python, types, typeerror

I am currently trying to finish a rounding function called my_round(), but there's one error I can't figure out. I keep receiving the error saying that "list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType" for the following line of code:

```
plus = num1[indexer1] + 1
```

This is located at the end of my script shown below:

```
def index_decider(listA, num2):
    # Use functions for inputs to set global variables

    
    for i in listA:
        if i == ".":
            # Create a variable to represent the ones place by indexing the occurence of ".", then subtracting 1.
            listA = list(listA)
            start = listA.index(i) - 1
            # Turn num2 into int because you can't add a string and an int.
            num2 = int(num2)
            # Add the user input to the variable which stores the one's place. This stores the index for where the user wishes to round to.
            start += num2
            print(start)
            return int(start)

def my_round():
    num1 = input_round1() 
    num2 = input_round2()
    listA = []
    num1 = list(num1)

    for i in num1:
        listA.append(i)

        indexer1 = index_decider(listA, num2)

        plus = num1[indexer1] + 1
        minus = num1[indexer1] - 1
```

Essentially, the way I tried to solve this was by allowing the user to input two numbers. The first number is the number to be rounded, and the 2nd number is the index one wishes to round to. This is done so I can iterate through up until that point in a later function, then apply the necessary rounding actions (i.e., replacing with 0s and round up/down)

So the main thrust of my question is "why can't I dispell this error?" Even if i change the variable type to a list, I still get this error. Futhermore, I am also confused why my 'indexer1' variable shows 'int | none' while the rest of my variables only show one data type. I'm assuming the problem lies behind this.

Comment: basically it is telling you that either `listA` was empty or `i` never was `'.'` in the `index_decider` function, hard to tell because you haven't provided sample input and expected output, also provide a complete [mre]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your index_decider doesn't return a value, you're passing a empty list as argument so your for loop doesn't run. or it doesn't match your if statement